# Outputting editText and textViews based off user input?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, textview

I was wondering if it was possible to ouput xml elements such as editText and textView based off user input. For example I'm making a simple game app and in the app you get taken to a new activity where it asks the amount of players. Based off the input (e.g. 5) I woulld like to display editText's and textViews so the players can be given names. Is this possible with Java and if so, how?

Comment: You can use the visibility property of the Views to switch between GONE and VISIBLE to hide or show the view defined in the Layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure is, though without having to go through XML.
Pass the number of players to the next activity as an argument. Then make sure you have a ViewGroup (LinearLayout for example) in the second activity's layout.

Then loop through and create the Views dynamically:

```
ViewGroup container = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

for( int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++ ){
    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    et.setHint(R.string.new_player_hint);// String providing a hint to the user
    container.addView(et);
}
```

You can put the EditTexts in a List or if that's all you'll have you can directly cycle over the ViewGroup's children to get their values later on:

```
for( int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++ ){

    String playerName = ((EditText) container.getChildAt(i)).getText().toString();

}
```

If you're going to have many possible players you should wrap the LinearLayout in a ScrollView.

Because you'll likely use this in onCreate remember that you can't rely on the EditText to save its own data in case the Activity is destroyed, so save them yourself and feed them back in when re-creating.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with ViewGroup? I'm quite the noob when it comes to android programming.

Comment: Views that can have children. ViewGroup extends View. So for instance LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, FrameLayout. For more info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup